# Can I make a Snort to read data coming to a network and detect if the value of data is intrusion or not?

Tags: java, networking, websocket, snort, ids

I am making an edge network configuration where I want to test the node data if it is an intrusion or not. For the testing environment, I am using a random integer generator to randomly generate integers and I want to configure snort and make rules so that if the data is outside a certain range, then flag it as an intrusion. Is it possible? What may be the possible rules for it? I am using the `ProcessBuilder` class in Java. What may the Java code look like?